# UIWebView Causing Watchdog Timeout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, timeout, watchdog

We have a fairly straightforward native iOS app that is almost ready to be submitted for approval save for one pesky bug. That is that in rare cases (when system memory is low? and only noticed on iPad (3,1)) when resuming the app, it hangs for 10 seconds and then crashes.

The app is basically a UIWebView with a lightweight shell around it for managing some iCloud key values. We're using the native google analytics, the content of our web view is using a cache manifest and local storage.

We're only able to reproduce the bug after intentionally hammering the system Safari app (by opening many large sites) until toggling between tabs causes safari to start refreshing each page (as though Safari / iOS has decided that to free up memory it's going to flush the contents of the already open tabs). Since our app is mostly just a WebView, we're wondering if the system is dumping our content. If that was all that happened, that would be fine … but instead, it hangs and crashes.

We know it's an 8badf00d / failed to resume in time … but we just don't know what's causing it.

I've posted our crash log below. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
Incident Identifier: 956DBEA0-ECA4-4E16-91F7-573A7AD7D44C
CrashReporter Key:   0d3d958fa8005603bcc173d27ae567507d0cbb19
Hardware Model:      iPad3,1
Process:         REDACTED [12885]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/REDACTED/REDACTED.app/REDACTED
Identifier:      REDACTED
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]
Date/Time:       2013-08-25 15:28:14.138 -0400
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Report Version:  104
Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0
Application Specific Information:
com.REDACTED.REDACTED failed to resume in time
Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 18.710 (user 18.710, system 0.000), 93% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 9.513, 47% CPU
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libRIP.A.dylib                0x32d9ee8c convolve_buffer + 108
1   libRIP.A.dylib                0x32d99fa0 separable_convolve + 704
2   libRIP.A.dylib                0x32d8f35e symmetric_convolve + 414
3   libRIP.A.dylib                0x32d8f052 RIPLayerSymmetricConvolve + 554
4   libRIP.A.dylib                0x32d8eda0 RIPLayerGaussianBlur + 464
5   libRIP.A.dylib                0x32d9184a rips_s_BltShapeShadow + 458
6   libRIP.A.dylib                0x32d9944e rips_s_BltShape + 94
7   libRIP.A.dylib                0x32d897a0 ripc_Render + 248
8   libRIP.A.dylib                0x32d8b722 ripc_DrawPath + 338
9   CoreGraphics                  0x32a6b4bc CGContextDrawPath + 144
10  WebCore                       0x38a53246 WebCore::GraphicsContext::fillPath(WebCore::Path const&) + 558
11  WebCore                       0x38b19518 WebCore::GraphicsContext::fillRectWithRoundedHole(WebCore::IntRect const&, WebCore::RoundedRect const&, WebCore::Color const&, WebCore::ColorSpace) + 396
12  WebCore                       0x389836ec WebCore::RenderBoxModelObject::paintBoxShadow(WebCore::PaintInfo const&, WebCore::IntRect const&, WebCore::RenderStyle const*, WebCore::ShadowStyle, bool, bool) + 1644
13  WebCore                       0x38982ba0 WebCore::RenderBox::paintBoxDecorations(WebCore::PaintInfo&, WebCore::IntPoint const&) + 348
14  WebCore                       0x3898152a WebCore::RenderBlock::paintObject(WebCore::PaintInfo&, WebCore::IntPoint const&) + 58
15  WebCore                       0x389828f4 WebCore::RenderBlock::paint(WebCore::PaintInfo&, WebCore::IntPoint const&) + 168
16  WebCore                       0x38980126 WebCore::RenderLayer::paintLayerContents(WebCore::RenderLayer*, WebCore::GraphicsContext*, WebCore::IntRect const&, unsigned int, WebCore::RenderObject*, WebCore::RenderRegion*, WTF::HashMap<WebCore::OverlapTestRequestClient*, WebCore::IntRect, WTF::PtrHash<WebCore::OverlapTestRequestClient*>, WTF::HashTraits<WebCore::OverlapTestRequestClient*>, WTF::HashTraits<WebCore::IntRect> >*, unsigned int) + 1086
17  WebCore                       0x3897fcc6 WebCore::RenderLayer::paintLayer(WebCore::RenderLayer*, WebCore::GraphicsContext*, WebCore::IntRect const&, unsigned int, WebCore::RenderObject*, WebCore::RenderRegion*, WTF::HashMap<WebCore::OverlapTestRequestClient*, WebCore::IntRect, WTF::PtrHash<WebCore::OverlapTestRequestClient*>, WTF::HashTraits<WebCore::OverlapTestRequestClient*>, WTF::HashTraits<WebCore::IntRect> >*, unsigned int) + 1078
18  WebCore                       0x38980552 WebCore::RenderLayer::paintLayerContents(WebCore::RenderLayer*, WebCore::GraphicsContext*, WebCore::IntRect const&, unsigned int, WebCore::RenderObject*, WebCore::RenderRegion*, WTF::HashMap<WebCore::OverlapTestRequestClient*, WebCore::IntRect, WTF::PtrHash<WebCore::OverlapTestRequestClient*>, WTF::HashTraits<WebCore::OverlapTestRequestClient*>, WTF::HashTraits<WebCore::IntRect> >*, unsigned int) + 2154
19  WebCore                       0x38aab67e WebCore::RenderLayerBacking::paintIntoLayer(WebCore::RenderLayer*, WebCore::GraphicsContext*, WebCore::IntRect const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, WebCore::RenderObject*) + 150
20  WebCore                       0x38aab4fa WebCore::RenderLayerBacking::paintContents(WebCore::GraphicsLayer const*, WebCore::GraphicsContext&, unsigned int, WebCore::IntRect const&) + 158
21  WebCore                       0x38aab452 WebCore::GraphicsLayer::paintGraphicsLayerContents(WebCore::GraphicsContext&, WebCore::IntRect const&) + 94
22  WebCore                       0x38aab37c __drawLayerContents_block_invoke_0 + 180
23  WebKit                        0x39240e14 WKCALayerEnumerateRectsBeingDrawnWithBlock + 56
24  WebCore                       0x38aaaf5c drawLayerContents(CGContext*, CALayer*, WebCore::PlatformCALayer*) + 520
25  QuartzCore                    0x3457c1ae CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 1806
26  QuartzCore                    0x3457b910 CA::Layer::display_() + 976
27  WebCore                       0x38aaad02 -[WebLayer display] + 50
28  QuartzCore                    0x34572936 CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 198
29  QuartzCore                    0x34572860 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 20
30  QuartzCore                    0x3457223e CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 234
31  QuartzCore                    0x3457204c CA::Transaction::commit() + 312
32  UIKit                         0x3496d13e _UIWindowUpdateVisibleContextOrder + 206
33  UIKit                         0x3496d00e +[UIWindow _prepareWindowsForAppResume] + 6
34  UIKit                         0x3496cae8 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationResumeEvent:] + 72
35  UIKit                         0x347c4d54 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1288
36  UIKit                         0x347c46c8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
37  UIKit                         0x347c4116 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6150
38  GraphicsServices              0x364b85a0 _PurpleEventCallback + 588
39  CoreFoundation                0x32991680 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
40  CoreFoundation                0x32990ee4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 208
41  CoreFoundation                0x3298fcb2 __CFRunLoopRun + 642
42  CoreFoundation                0x32902eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
43  CoreFoundation                0x32902d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
44  GraphicsServices              0x364b72e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
45  UIKit                         0x348182fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
46  REDACTED                    0x00087828 main (main.m:16)
47  libdyld.dylib                 0x3ac89b1c start + 0
Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad40648 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib             0x3ac70974 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 792
2   libdispatch.dylib             0x3ac70654 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 32
Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad500fc __psynch_mutexwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3ac99124 pthread_mutex_lock + 388
2   WebCore                       0x388f4418 _ZL17_WebTryThreadLockb + 184
3   WebCore                       0x388f434a _ZL14WebRunLoopLockP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 42
4   CoreFoundation                0x329916ca __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 18
5   CoreFoundation                0x3298f9bc __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 272
6   CoreFoundation                0x3298fde8 __CFRunLoopRun + 952
7   CoreFoundation                0x32902eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
8   CoreFoundation                0x32902d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
9   WebCore                       0x388f2500 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 440
10  libsystem_c.dylib             0x3aca930e _pthread_start + 306
11  libsystem_c.dylib             0x3aca91d4 thread_start + 4
Thread 3 name:  com.crashlytics.MachExceptionServer
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad3feb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad40048 mach_msg + 36
2   REDACTED                    0x000ab1a4 CLSMachExceptionServer + 116
3   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3aca930e _pthread_start + 306
4   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3aca91d4 thread_start + 4
Thread 4 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad5008c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3aca1d2a _pthread_cond_wait + 642
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3aca1aa0 pthread_cond_timedwait + 40
3   JavaScriptCore                0x368adc70 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 104
4   JavaScriptCore                0x369bf552 JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 78
5   JavaScriptCore                0x369d1fa8 _ZN3WTFL19wtfThreadEntryPointEPv + 12
6   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3aca930e _pthread_start + 306
7   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3aca91d4 thread_start + 4
Thread 5 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad5008c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3aca1d2a _pthread_cond_wait + 642
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acabf14 pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   JavaScriptCore                0x36952f3c JSC::SlotVisitor::drainFromShared(JSC::SlotVisitor::SharedDrainMode) + 144
4   JavaScriptCore                0x36952e7c JSC::MarkStackThreadSharedData::markingThreadMain() + 140
5   JavaScriptCore                0x369d1fa8 _ZN3WTFL19wtfThreadEntryPointEPv + 12
6   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3aca930e _pthread_start + 306
7   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3aca91d4 thread_start + 4
Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad3feb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad40048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                0x32991040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                0x3298fd9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                0x32902eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                0x32902d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   Foundation                    0x3324f3d0 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 304
7   Foundation                    0x332d2e80 __NSThread__main__ + 968
8   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3aca930e _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3aca91d4 thread_start + 4
Thread 7 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad3feb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad40048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                0x32991040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                0x3298fd9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                0x32902eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                0x32902d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                       0x3898cd02 _ZN7WebCoreL15runLoaderThreadEPv + 138
7   JavaScriptCore                0x369d1fa8 _ZN3WTFL19wtfThreadEntryPointEPv + 12
8   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3aca930e _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3aca91d4 thread_start + 4
Thread 8 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad50594 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                0x329951f2 __CFSocketManager + 674
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3aca930e _pthread_start + 306
3   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3aca91d4 thread_start + 4
Thread 9 name:  WebCore: LocalStorage
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad5008c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3aca1d2a _pthread_cond_wait + 642
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3acabf14 pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   JavaScriptCore                0x368adc42 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 58
4   WebCore                       0x38b06e88 WTF::PassOwnPtr<WebCore::StorageTask> WTF::MessageQueue<WebCore::StorageTask>::waitForMessageFilteredWithTimeout<bool ()(WebCore::StorageTask*)>(WTF::MessageQueueWaitResult&, bool (&)(WebCore::StorageTask*), double) + 52
5   WebCore                       0x38b06e3c WebCore::StorageThread::threadEntryPoint() + 120
6   JavaScriptCore                0x369d1fa8 _ZN3WTFL19wtfThreadEntryPointEPv + 12
7   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3aca930e _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3aca91d4 thread_start + 4
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x3ad50d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3ac9ecf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3ac9ea12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib             0x3ac9e8a0 start_wqthread + 4
Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1
```

EDIT: Adding our AppDelegate.m functions:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  REDACTED
//
//  Created by REDACTED on 5/8/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 REDACTED. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "QSNavigationBar.h"
#import "QSUtils.h"
#import "QSInAppPurchaseHelper.h"
#import "GAI.h"
#import "Reachability.h"
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) Reachability* internetReach;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize internetReach = _internetReach;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // customize appearance
    [QSInAppPurchaseHelper sharedInstance];

    // plist used to populate user defaults
    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"REDACTED" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dict];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

    self.internetReach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    [self.internetReach startNotifier];
    [self setReachabilityStatus:self.internetReach];

    // Optional: automatically send uncaught exceptions to Google Analytics.
    [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
    // Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
    [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
    // Optional: set debug to YES for extra debugging information.
    [GAI sharedInstance].debug = NO;
    // Create tracker instance.
    id<GAITracker> tracker;
    tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"REDACTED"];

    // register to observe notifications from the icloud store
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(storeDidChange:) name: NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification object: [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore]];

    // get changes that might have happened while this
    // instance of your app wasn't running
    [[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] synchronize];

    [self customizeAppearance];

    [Crashlytics startWithAPIKey:@"REDACTED"];

    return YES;
}

- (void)storeDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [QSUtils resolve];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"iCloudChange" object:nil];
}

- (void)customizeAppearance
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[QSUtils colorFromHex:@"#333333"]];
}

- (void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification*)note
{
    NSLog(@"!!!Reachability Changed!!!");
    Reachability* curReach = [note object];
    NSParameterAssert([curReach isKindOfClass:[Reachability class]]);
    [self setReachabilityStatus:curReach];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reachabilityChanged" object:nil];
}

- (void)setReachabilityStatus:(Reachability*)curReach
{
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [curReach currentReachabilityStatus];

    switch (netStatus) {
        case NotReachable: {
            [QSUtils setHasInternetConnection:NO];
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        case ReachableViaWiFi: {
            [QSUtils setHasInternetConnection:YES];
            break;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Added our AppDelegate.m functions above ...

Comment: Did u found solution?

Comment: Not yet … still stumped.